# How to get the new array with only unique ids during the filtering and mapping in Js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

I am trying to get dropdwon items from tags and keywords. I tried to bring them into the same format for each of them filtering and mapping like this:

```
  const productsWithTags = products
          .filter(product => !!product.tagId)
          .map(item => ({
            id: item.tagId,
            name: item.tagName,
          }))
```

The point is that it adds duplicates since some products have the same tagIds how can I keep this array unique?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to select distinct items by tagId,then map the result

```js
const products= [{tagId:1,tagName:"Tag 1"}, {tagId:2,tagName:"Tag 2"}, {tagId:3,tagName:"Tag 3"}, {tagId:1,tagName:"Tag 1-2"}, {tagId:3,tagName:"Tag 3-2"}, {tagId:2,tagName:"Tag 2-2"}]
const productsWithTags = products
          .filter(function(value,index,self){return self.indexOf(self.find(item =>item.tagId==value.tagId)) === index})
          .map(item => ({
            id: item.tagId,
            name: item.tagName,
          }))
console.log(productsWithTags)
```

Comment: You can also use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) directly instead of `insteadOf` + `find`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of coercing the `tagId` property to a `Boolean`, you have to create a lookup table that tells you if the `tagId` of an item has already been seen/visited and then filter based on that result.

You can see a working example below with annotations.

```js
const products = [
  {
    tagId: 'a',
    tagName: 'Tag A'
  },
  {
    tagId: 'b',
    tagName: 'Tag B'
  },
  {
    tagId: 'a',
    tagName: 'Tag A'
  },
  {
    tagId: 'c',
    tagName: 'Tag C'
  }
];

function uniqueBy(property) {
  let seen = Object.create(null); // closure, tells us the already seen id's
  return function (item) {        // predicate function
    let key = item[property];     // get the "key" value (here: tagId)
    if (seen[key] == null) {      // is the key not inside the seen closure?
      seen[key] = 1;              // then add it and
      return true;                // accept the item
    }
    return false;                 // otherwise reject the item
  };
}

const result = products.
  filter(uniqueBy('tagId')).      // use "uniqueBy" to create a predicate
  map(product => {
    return {
      id: product.tagId,
      name: product.tagName
    };
  });
  
console.log(result);
```

*Hint: You can make that more performant by avoiding one iteration step. How? Use `.reduce` instead of `.filter` and `.map`.*

```js
const products = [
  {
    tagId: 'a',
    tagName: 'Tag A'
  },
  {
    tagId: 'b',
    tagName: 'Tag B'
  },
  {
    tagId: 'a',
    tagName: 'Tag A'
  },
  {
    tagId: 'c',
    tagName: 'Tag C'
  }
];

function uniqueBy(property) {
  let seen = Object.create(null); // closure, tells us the already seen id's
  return function (item) {        // predicate function
    let key = item[property];     // get the "key" value (here: tagId)
    if (seen[key] == null) {      // is the key not inside the seen closure?
      seen[key] = 1;              // then add it and
      return true;                // accept the item
    }
    return false;                 // otherwise reject the item
  };
}


function filterMap(filterer, mapper) {
  return function (accumulator, item) {
    return filterer(item)
      ? [...accumulator, mapper(item)]
      : accumulator;
  }
}

const result = products.
  reduce(
    filterMap(
      uniqueBy('tagId'),
      product => {
          return {
            id: product.tagId,
            name: product.tagName
          };
      }
    ),
    []
  );
  
console.log(result);
```